# editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath isn't getting called (So a delete button is showing up)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, tablecell

I'm playing around with moving uitableviewcells, and for whatever reason,

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
           editingstyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone; //<-- bp set on it
}
```

isn't getting called (I've set a breakpoint on it) - so the table is showing the delete option, but I don't want that. Here's my implementation:

```
@implementation MoveItController
@synthesize mList;

- (IBAction)moveButton
{
    [self.tableView setEditing:!self.tableView.editing animated:YES];

    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:(self.tableView.editing)? @"Done" : @"Move"];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if (mList == nil)
    {
        mList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"$1", @"$2", @"$5", @"$10", @"$20", @"$50", @"$100", nil];
    }

    UIBarButtonItem *mvButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"Move" 
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                 target:self 
                                 action:@selector(moveButton)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = mvButton;
    [mvButton release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

// Table datasource methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [mList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *moveItCellId = @"moveItCellId";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:moveItCellId];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:moveItCellId] autorelease];
        cell.showsReorderControl = YES;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [mList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
           editingstyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath
toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    id object = [[mList objectAtIndex:[fromIndexPath row]] retain];
    [mList removeObjectAtIndex:[fromIndexPath row]];
    [mList insertObject:object atIndex:[toIndexPath row]];
    [object release];                 
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [mList release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

No warnings at compile time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try capitalizing the method name properly

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
           editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

That's with the `S` in `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` capitalized.  ObjC selectors are case sensitive.  The table view does not think it's delegate responds to the method you are trying to provide a return value to.

Comment: Damn - I like tripple checked that! haha, thanks. I wish xcode threw a warning, like for a similar method signature...which I thought it usually does. +1 thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You need to set multiple selection to NO in editing mode

```
self.tableview.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = NO;
```

Comment: - I had set 'allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing' to YES to allow for 2-finger selection. I needed to set it to NO during table editing.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason might be that you also need to implement

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
  forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: That was my issue:.. when you remove this method (`commitEditingStyle`) and then put a breakpoint in `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath`, it won't be called any longer and the default editing style becomes none

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath (and other delegates) not being called is if the control does not have it's delegate outlet connected to the File's Owner.

Yes, this is obvious but it's easily overlooked.